# Active record, find common interests for different Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a classes `User` that `has_many` `Interests`.

Now when I get a user, I want to get the common interests with an other user.

How could I do with ActiveRecord ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
the_user = User.find(1)
interest_ids = the_user.interest_ids
users_with_common_interests = User.includes(:interests)
    .where(interests: { id: interest_ids })
    .where.not(id: the_user)
```

Comment: Good, this gives me the users with common interests, I'll try this way to get the list of common interests for a given user id.